# How to take input whenever I want during endless loop?

Tags: c, multithreading, input, conditional-statements, command

My task is to make a game simulation that uses threads to simulate work. If the thread's been given command to do another work it should pause it's first work and start the new work. How to implement it in C? I've tried with separate function for the input and signaling a condition variable but when it enters the giveCommand() function it just waits for input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char command;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t condVar;
void giveCommand()
{
    scanf("%c", command);
    pthread_cond_signal (&condVar);
    return;
}
void *thread(void *N)
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        //do its work
        pthread_cond_timedwait(&condVar, &mutex, 500000);// if command hasn't been given, continue work
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_cond_init(&condVar, NULL);
        while(giveCommand());
    }
}
    int main()
    {
        int i;
        int error;
        pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&condVar, NULL);
        while(1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
            {
                error = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, simulateWorker, NULL);
                if (error != 0) printf("Error creating thread!");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
            {
                error = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
                if (error != 0) printf("Error joining thread!");
            }
            pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutex);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In `giveCommand` I think `pthread_cond_signal &condVar;` should be `pthread_cond_signal(&condVar);`

Comment: You also seem to be missing a parentheses in the `thread` function. Likely before `while(giveCommand());`

Comment: "If the thread's been given command to do another work it should pause it's first work and start the new work." Really? FIFO is much more common.

Comment: @Chris error while rewriting the code for stackoverflow, thanks.. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Yunnosch i'm entering just one command (in one loop cycle) and it is at the end of the thread's original work but it should be while the mutex is locked. That's why I do it that way.